# How to prove geometric mean is smaller than the arithmetic mean for a continuous distribution?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration

For discrete probability distribution, the **geometric mean** is defined as ${{\rm{E}}_{\rm{G}}}X = {\mu _G} = \sqrt[{\mathop \sum \limits_i {p_i}}]{{\mathop \prod \limits_i x_i^{{p_i}}}} = \mathop \prod \limits_i x_i^{{p_i}}$

For sample, the geometric mean is defined as ${\bar X_G} = \sqrt[n]{{\mathop \prod \limits_{i = 1}^n {X_i}}}$. It is obvious that ${\rm{ln}}{\bar X_G} = \overline {{\rm{ln}}X} $.

For continuous distribution, the geometric mean is defined indirectly by ${\rm{ln}}\left( {{{\rm{E}}_{\rm{G}}}X} \right) = {\rm{ln}}{\mu _G} = {\rm{E}}\left( {{\rm{ln}}X} \right) = \mathop \smallint \limits_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } \left( {{\rm{ln}}x} \right)f\left( x \right)dx$

The geometric mean is always less or equal to the arithmetic mean. The is because logarithm function is a strictly concave function. For discrete distribution, we have ${\rm{ln}}\mu  = {\rm{ln}}\mathop \sum \nolimits{x_i}{p_i}$, and ${\rm{ln}}{\mu _G} = \mathop \sum \nolimits\left( {{\rm{ln}}{x_i}} \right){p_i}$ which is a convex sum. It naturally follows that ${\rm{ln}}\mu  \ge {\rm{ln}}{\mu _G}$ and hence $\mu  \ge {\mu _G}$. For sample geometric mean, ${\rm{ln}}\bar X = {\rm{ln}}\left( {\frac{1}{n}\mathop \sum \nolimits{X_i}} \right)$ and ${\rm{ln}}{\bar X_G} = \frac{1}{n}\mathop \sum \nolimits{\rm{ln}}{X_i}$, it is also obvious that $\bar X \ge {\bar X_G}$.

**Here comes the question**, how to prove that for the continuous distribution, the same statement holds, that is $\ln \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {xf(x)dx}  \ge \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {(\ln x)f(x)dx} $? ($f(x)$ is a probability density function such that $\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {f(x)dx}  = 1$).

There have been similar questions posted here but they are all for discrete cases. I also searched the Internet and could not find a solution. So I think it would be very helpful if someone can help prove it. Thank you!

Comment: You may want to restrict your distribution to positive numbers if you are taking their logarithms

Comment: Do you know Jensen's inequality (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form)?